# List each month between date range. Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am asking for help for an issue i've been trying to solve for hours and hours, in vain.
I am working with google query() on google spreadsheets.
So i have this kind of table (lets say A1:E3)

| Client | Bank receipt | Start Date | End date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | #1 | 14/10/2021 | 31/10/2021 | 500 |
| John | #2 | 14/10/2021 | 31/12/2021 | 500 |

To make it clearer, the bank receipts are values that have a start date and an end date. So that bank receipt #2 covers 500 for october, november and december.
What i am trying to do is a chronological table (with months in columns) that shows me the amount of bank receipt coverage for john during the year, so that to get this kind of result:

|  |  | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Bank receipts | 1000 | 500 | 500 |

This is the first step of a longer query but i need to get data returned this way to be able to go on.

I tried to look for ways to return every month of date range but only founds posts talking abount google scripts i can't play with. I also tried using SEQUENCE() which seemed to work with some tricks until i put from 2021/12/15 to 2022/03/31 and it returned like 14 because of the year changing. So i am quite out of solutions. I precise that i am new to using google queries so i might miss some obvious things.

Thanks a lot to who might help

Comment: Is the end date always the last day of a month? That would make it a bit easier.

Comment: Yes it will for simplicity purpose indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a fairly simple demo for 2 rows X 3 columns which you could build on:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult({1,1},if((C2:C3<=eomonth(G2,{0,1,2}))*(D2:D3>=eomonth(G2,{0,1,2})),E2:E3,0)))
```

[image]

Will give a more complete solution later.

---

This is a more dynamic version of the formula

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(sequence(1,counta(A2:A),1,0),
if((C2:index(C:C,counta(C:C))<=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0)))*
(D2:index(D:D,counta(D:D))>=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0))),E2:index(E:E,counta(E:E)),0)))
```

but it's using the same principle

(1) Use eomonth with sequence to make a single-row array of month-ends (31/10/21, 30/11/21, 31/12/21 etc.)

(2) Compare those dates with the date ranges in your data to see which of them are contained in each range, and where they match, produce a 2d array with the amounts in it with the months going across and the data rows going down

(3) Use mmult to get the column totals of the 2d array (this is a standard method for getting column totals [shown here being used in Excel](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-column-totals))

[image]

I've used a simpler formula to get the months starting at I1

```
=ArrayFormula(edate(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M"),0)))
```

Comment: OK thank you, i am waiting for the more complete solution then as this one is quite hard to interprete for me honestly. I looked for information on mmult() but didn't understand how'd you built it like that, also eomonth with {} and the '*' in between are another subtleties i don't get

Comment: OK i understood the use of {...} is there for the use of arrays (absolute values instead of cells right?). I am also 'translating' the formulas since in Europe we have "," as decimal separator and have to use '\' instead. So it only adds a bit of difficulty

Comment: Wow awesome, thank you sir! I have adapted the formula to my language (italian) + european functions' format and i can tell it works fine! But now, most important for me, is to understand WHY it is working. I understand your explanations and most of what is in the formula (one by one), though there are still some nested functions in other nested functions that make it difficult to visualize, so i am deconstructing it and rebuilding it step by step to make it mine. I will post here when i am done, it might take a few days. Again, thank you very much for the skills, help and availability!

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks for all the tips and solutions, it all works.
Now I would have a further step that is trickier than I thought. I need to execute this, but grouping the returned values by a label that will be present in the rows, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ch9r.png

The difficult point is that I cannot execute a query that would also 'group by' the result as I thought in the beginning because of the array.formula(). So I guess that I would need to apply the 'array.formula()' already to the good dataset (filtered by A, then B, etc). Though I would like to avoid creating X datasets but rather find a way to do it dynamically.
I saw that you can't use query() inside an array.formula(), but the opposite works.

I have clear in mind how to do it with a query(), but the array.formula() is complicating it quite a bit.

I am not asking to have all the work done by maybe you could give me tips on how to build it? Which are the steps/functions you would advise me to use? Then I'll try and figure it out by my self and post the result here.

Comment: Please consider asking your further question as a separate one. Because of the layout of the system here, there isn't a way for anybody to answer your further query except perhaps in the comments to your answer, where things might get lost or cluttered, and formating options are limited (and that's not what comments are for anyway).

Comment: OK i will do, thanks