# Only apply complex arrayformula() to rows with certain value in dataset

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a quite complext formula (i mean that is complex to me) that [Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe) helped me building to aggregate values and ordering them by months in a row(you can find the details in [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539215/list-each-month-between-date-range-google-query)  but i think you'll only need the final formula which is:

`=ArrayFormula(mmult(sequence(1,counta(A2:A),1,0), if((C2:index(C:C,counta(C:C))<=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0)))* (D2:index(D:D,counta(D:D))>=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0))),E2:index(E:E,counta(E:E)),0)))`

and here is the [result -> [J1:U1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO2Qm.png)

Now, what i would need to do as the final step is to be able to group data by a certain label (John or Jane in the example) on separate rows, but mantaining the order/aggregate by month on the row. On the example, this would mean having one row with only 'John' data and below, one with 'Jane' values.

I am struggling to understand how to adapt the formula to do so.
I have tried:

- Using another array to first return a list of these labels with query(unique()) or something like that, but then i struggle looping in it with the other formula.
- A bit more simplistic but it could work after all: on the 1st row (the cell next to where the data will be returned) writing 'John', on row 2 'Jane' and then using filter() to only pull data that matches. The 'John, Jane' value is for the example but the real labels won't be that many, the list of labels don't need to be dynamic.

The thing with these solutions is that they work when used separately, but i can't figure out how to nest this in the first arrayformula() that Tom helped me with...As i am just beginning with the google sheets queries.

I don't really need necessarily the complete formula/code but maybe just directions or tips to visualize the way i could solve this.

Thanks to all who might contribute

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hindsight I might have done better to go down the route of using a query to calculate the sums on my previous answer rather than Mmult.

This uses the same method as before to create a 2d array of amounts vs dates (going across) and individuals (going down). Then it uses Textjoin to generate a query to group by name with the required number of columns.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A,if((C2:C<=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0)))* (D2:D>=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0))),E2:E,0)},
"select Col1,sum(Col"&textjoin("),sum(Col",,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,2))&") where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))
```

[image]

This is the generated query

```
select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7),sum(Col8),sum(Col9),sum(Col10),sum(Col11),sum(Col12),sum(Col13) where Col1 is not null group by Col1
```

---

Ideally there should be an extra section saying label sum(Col2) '' etc. to suppress the 'Sum' headers.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A,if((C2:C<=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0)))* (D2:D>=eomonth(G2,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,0))),E2:E,0)},
"select Col1,sum(Col"&textjoin("),sum(Col",,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,2))&") where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col" & textjoin(") '', sum(Col",,sequence(1,datedif(G2,H2,"M")+1,2)) & ") ''"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, as i did with your former formula, which i now have understood and have been using, i will try to dissect this one too since many pieces are unknown to me (i haven't been able to understand the meaning of using {} instead of (), i thought it was about absolutes but it seems i am wrong). I'll come back when i am ready. Thanks again for your time