# How to fetch accurate monthly closing data from Google Finance in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am trying to fetch historical monthly closing Google Finance data of a stock into Google Sheets using the formula :-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2021,2,1), "daily"), 
 {"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

However, this formula is not displaying accurate monthly closing prices in Google Sheets.

Is there a different formula or function that I can use to fetch accurate monthly closing data from Google Finance into Google Sheets?

I tried using:-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TEXT(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), DATE(2021,2,1), "daily"), 
 {"yyyy mm", "@"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 0))
```

But it is showing incorrect monthly closing price of a stock.

Comment: `However, this formula is not displaying accurate monthly closing prices in Google Sheets.` Would you please edit your question: 1) explain if these are not the "monthly closing prices" then what are they?; 2) show the values returned by the formula, and the values that you believe should be returned by the formula.

Answer (score 0):

- Enter the start date and end date in cells A1 and A2,
- then try this formula:

Note: Cells A1 and A2 can be removed, and the dates can be hard-coded in the formula if necessary.

---

```
=query({
    {"Date";ArrayFormula(eomonth(EDATE(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),DATE(year($B$2),month($B$2),day($B$2)),"M"),1,0)),0))},
    {"Price";MAP(
        ArrayFormula(eomonth(EDATE(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),DATE(year($B$2),month($B$2),day($B$2)),"M"),1,0)),0)),
        LAMBDA(dates,index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "close",dates,), 2,2))
    )}}, 
    "select Col1, Col2"
)
```

---

**Logic**

- Generate a `SEQUENCE` of dates:
  `=ArrayFormula(eomonth(EDATE(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(DATE(year($B$1),month($B$1),day($B$1)),DATE(year($B$2),month($B$2),day($B$2)),"M"),1,0)),0))`

h/t @TomSharpe [List each month between date range. Google Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540288/1330560)

- `GOOGLEFINANCE` to return prices for given date array:

`=MAP(  ArrayFormula(eomonth(EDATE(DATE(2020,1,1),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(DATE(2020,1,1),DATE(2021,2,1),"M"),1,0)),0)), LAMBDA(dates,index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "close",dates,), 2,2)) )`

h/t [www.liveflow.io: How to Use MAP Function in Google Sheets](https://www.liveflow.io/product-guides/how-to-use-map-function-in-google-sheets)

- Wrap both arrays in a `QUERY`

---

**Results**

[image: snapshot]

---